# Highlight cells as a function of string length

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, string-length

I have a situation where the user imports a file, and the file name/location are printed to cell A1. As it stands, the highlighted cells are hard coded.

```
'Retreive File Name
 Worksheets("Header_Info").Range("A1") = Ret
 Worksheets("Header_Info").Range("A1:K1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

In some situations, the file name/location length exceeds the highlighted cells. I would like to make this more dynamic and have the highlighted cells become a function of the length of the file name/location string.

[image: File name/location]

I've attempted to determine the last column used, but this does not work, as the entire text remains in cell A1 and is superimposed on the adjacent cells, not actually filling them.

```
Option Explicit
Sub HighlightString()
'This macro will highlight the number of cells as a function of the string length

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim strLength As Long
    Dim cond1 As FormatConditions

    Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToLeft))

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rng.FormatConditions.Delete

    strLength = Len(Range("A1"))

    'Conditional Rules
    Set cond1 = rng.FormatCondition.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, strLength)

    'Apply Condition
    With cond1
    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With

End Sub
```

With this, I'm getting a run-time error '438' probably because `strLength` is not supported in this context. How can I overcome this?

Comment: So it's not an option to adjust the width of `A1` and just highlight that one cell?

Comment: I could merge A1, but then I will have this constant yellow banner spanning the width across the top of the screen.

Comment: I think it's going to be a lot harder otherwise to do what you want. Could be wrong though.

Comment: That may be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please. It uses a trick: Copy the range to be fit two columns over the used range, auto fit the column, uses its `ColumnWidth` to make the adjustment and finally clear the temporary cell:

```
Sub testMatchOnlyACellWidth()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastEmptyCol As Long
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastEmptyCol = sh.UsedRange.Columns.count + 2
 sh.Range("A1").Copy sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol)
 sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol).EntireColumn.AutoFit

 sh.Range("A1").ColumnWidth = sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol).ColumnWidth
 sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol).Clear
End Sub
```

To fit at the header text length **all cells from range "A1:K1"**, use the next code, please:

```
Sub testMatchCellsWidth()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastEmptyCol As Long, i As Long
 Set sh = Worksheets("Header_Info")
 lastEmptyCol = sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 2
 sh.Range("A1:K1").Copy sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol)
 sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol), sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol + 10)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
 Stop
 Debug.Print sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol + 1 - 1).address
 For i = 1 To 11
    sh.Cells(1, i).ColumnWidth = sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol - 1 + i).ColumnWidth
    sh.Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol - 1 + i).Clear
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot adjust `A1` width to autofit...there is data in the `A1` column a few rows down.

Comment: @Cody W.: So, `AutoFit` is not suitable. Would you need to **set the A1 cell width in order to match its text length**?

Comment: This still leaves the `A` col oversized, messing up the sheet format.

Comment: Not possible! Please run the code line by line and check what it does... Did you check the code as it is? Even with minor changes...

Comment: @Cody W.: I feel the need to emphasize that the above code is an example to show you how to fit *"A1" cell** to its text length. If you tried to copy all the range ("A1:K1") instead of "A1" it will certainly not work. It can be done, but in a different way. All the range can be copied and autoFit its columns, but **each column width** must be set individually. I can show you how, if this is your problem...

Comment: @Cody W.: Updated the code with a version able to fit all cells in range "A1:K1". Please, confirm that it works as you need.

Comment: So this works, with 2 caveats. Col `A` needs to be resized before the script ends, and col `O` should either be resized or removed. Otherwise, this works as intended.Thanks!

Comment: @Cody W.:  What do you mean  by "Col A needs to be resized before the script ends"? This is what the code does!. If you consider that clearing the temporarily used range columns is not enough, instead of `sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol - 1 + i).Clear` you can use `sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol - 1 + i).EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToRight`. So, does the code do what you need?

Comment: Yes, and thank you. I don't have enough rep to vote though. Frustrating.

Comment: @Cody W.: Glad I could help! But in such a case you can tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... :) And it is more important then a vote up (even in terms of reputation...).

Answer (score 0):

Modified from an unknown user...

```
Sub HighlightString()

    'Supress Active Screen Updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Storing initial values somewhere else
    For i = 1 To 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = ""
    Next

    For i = 1 To 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)

        actual = 0

        ' Calculate the cell width
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            back = Columns(1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
            Columns(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
            actual = Columns(1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
            Columns(1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = back
        End If

        col = 1
        While actual > 0
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    
            actual = actual - Columns(col).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
            col = col + 1
        Wend

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = ""
    Next

    ' Restoring initial values
    For i = 1 To 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = ""
    Next

    'Allow Active Screen Updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Works well for the intended purpose.

Comment: A user posted a version of the `sub`, and while I was exploring it, the post was removed. Not sure what happened, but thanks!